# How to prevent inserting a new line on using ctrl+n for autocomplete?

Tags: autocompletion

When I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to autocomplete words a newline is inserted when I select a word from the list by pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

I don't want that, I want it to just insert the word and place the cursor at the end of the word.

Comment: This link may be helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162528/select-an-item-in-vim-autocomplete-list-without-inserting-line-break

Comment: Yup It's helpful, thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162528/select-an-item-in-vim-autocomplete-list-without-inserting-line-break) was asked on the Unix/Linux stack exchange.

The answer was found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162567).

## Summarizing

As the [manual states](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#popupmenu-completion):

```
There are three states:
1. A complete match has been inserted, e.g., after using CTRL-N or CTRL-P.
2. A cursor key has been used to select another match.  The match was not
   inserted then, only the entry in the popup menu is highlighted.
3. Only part of a match has been inserted and characters were typed or the
   backspace key was used.  The list of matches was then adjusted for what is
   in front of the cursor.
```

It looks like your selection happens during state 1, as referenced in the Unix/Linux stack exchange.  The short solution is to use `<C-Y>`.

Another [additional solution](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Make_Vim_completion_popup_menu_work_just_like_in_an_IDE) for remapping is:

`:inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<C-g>u\<CR>"`

The above mapping will change the behavior of the  key when the popup menu is visible. In that case the Enter key will simply select the highlighted menu item, just as  does.

### Additional Mappings for Popup Menu

Taken from the [previous link](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Make_Vim_completion_popup_menu_work_just_like_in_an_IDE):
These two mappings further improve the completion popup menu:

```
inoremap <expr> <C-n> pumvisible() ? '<C-n>' :
  \ '<C-n><C-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>Down>" : ""<CR>'
```

```
inoremap <expr> <M-,> pumvisible() ? '<C-n>' :
  \ '<C-x><C-o><C-n><C-p><C-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>Down>" : ""<CR>'
```

In the above mappings, the first will make  work the way it normally does; however, when the menu appears, the  key will be simulated. What this accomplishes is it keeps a menu item always highlighted. This way you can keep typing characters to narrow the matches, and the nearest match will be selected so that you can hit Enter at any time to insert it. In the above mappings, the second one is a little more exotic: it simulates  to bring up the omni completion menu, then it simulates  to remove the longest common text, and finally it simulates  again to keep a match highlighted.